# maxRequestLength in selfhost? File size>100kb will not upload

Tags: asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I encounter a problem that when upload file size large than 100kb, web api controller will not be called. I search for a while and found that maybe I should set maxRequestLength in webconfig. But how to set it in self host?

the client

```
public async Task<bool> Upload(DeviceFile file,string path)
{
    var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    var md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,bufferSize:4096,useAsync:true);
    fileStream.Position = 0;
    var hash = md5.ComputeHash(fileStream);
    fileStream.Position = 0;

    formData.Add(
            new StreamContent(fileStream),
            file.Name,
            file.Name,
            new {
               Info = file.Info,
            }
        );

    request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
    request.Content = formData;
    request.RequestUri = new Uri(client.BaseAddress,"api/file/");

    try
    {
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.logger.Log(ex.ToString(), Category.Info, Priority.None);
    }

    return true;
}
```

the server controller

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Add()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider("D:/");

    try
    {
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        // This illustrates how to get the file names.
        foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
            Console.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
        }

        foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
        {
            foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, val));
            }
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MaxReceivedMessageSize can be set on the self-host config object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.selfhost.httpselfhostconfiguration.maxreceivedmessagesize(v=vs.108).aspx#feedback

Comment: thanks again, I set httpsConfig.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 655360;
            httpsConfig.MaxBufferSize = 655360;